# "Cannot read property 'length' of undefined" ao utilizar array de arrays

Tags: javascript

Uma professora de programação, cansada de que os estudantes cheguem tarde, decidiu que vai cancelar a aula se há poucos presentes.

Ela representa a entrada dos estudantes como um array de tempos de chegada tarde, em minutos. Por exemplo, se um estudante chegou 10 minutos atrasado, outro 5 minutos antes da hora, outro com 3 minutos de atraso, e outro pontual, poderá representar assim:

```
var alunosDaSegunda = [10, -5, 3, 0];
```

Com essa informação e a quantidade mínima de estudantes para que suceda o curso, a professora quer saber se a aula acontecerá. Por exemplo, supondo que a quantidade mínima de estudantes para que a aula aconteça é de 2 alunos, então o curso da segunda-feira se realizará, porque houve um estudante que foi pontual e um estudante que chegou cedo.

```
acontece(alunosDaSegunda, 2)
true
```

Mas se a quantidade mínima fosse 3, a aula não aconteceria:

```
acontece(alunosDaSegunda, 3)
false
```

**Escreva as seguintes funções: 1. acontece, que diz se a aula sucederá de acordo com o array dos estudantes que entraram. 2. aberturas, que utiliza um array com os arrays dos estudantes que entraram nos outros dias, e a quantidade mínima de estudantes, e diga quais os dias em que as aulas aconteceram e quais não. Por exemplo:**

```
aberturas([alunosDaSegunda, alunosDaTerça, alunosDaQuarta], 2)
[true, false, false]
```

Eu já resolvi a primeira parte do código, porém essa função 'aberturas()' que esta dando erro quando executo. Segue o código que escrevi.

---

```
var alunosDaSegunda = [10, -5, 3, 0, -2];
var alunosDaTerca = [5,-3,-8,-15,0];
var alunosDaQuarta = [0, -5, 4, 5, 10];

function acontece(chegada_alunos, min_alunos) {
  var alunos = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i <= chegada_alunos.length; i++) {
    if (chegada_alunos[i] <= 0) {
      alunos = alunos + 1;
    }
  }
  return alunos >= min_alunos;
}

function aberturas(dia_aulas, minimo_alunos) {
  var aulas_v = [];
  for (let a = 0; a <= dia_aulas.length; a++) {
    aulas_v.push(acontece(dia_aulas[a], minimo_alunos));
  }
  return aulas_v;
}
```

Quando tento executar ele me apresenta esse erro:

```
aberturas([alunosDaSegunda, alunosDaTerca, alunosDaQuarta], 2)
solution.js:17
for (let i = 0; i <= chegada_alunos.length; i++) {
^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
at acontece (solution.js:17:38)
at aberturas (solution.js:27:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (solution.js:34:31)
at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:441:10)
at startup (node.js:139:18)
at node.js:968:3
```

Comment: `for (let a = 0; a <= dia_aulas.length; a++)`, dessa forma o valor de `a` varia entre 0 e 3, inclusive, mas no *array* você só possui os índices 0, 1 e 2. A sua condição de laço deve ser `a < dia_aulas.length`.

Comment: Aproveitando, nas próximas perguntas busque elaborar um título mais descritivo sobre o problema. "Exercício Aulas" não descreve o que você está fazendo e qual é o problema a ser solucionado na pergunta. Também atente-se a consistência das informações, para evitar colocar a mensagem de erro diferente do código que postou, como fez nessa pergunta, onde no erro consta `chegada_alunos.length` e no código consta `dia_aulas.length`. Isso não faz sentido.

Comment: Funcionou! Muito obrigado! Obrigado também pela dica...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Olá! O motivo do erro acima é relacionado ao fato de você estar buscando em um loop (for) os dias indicados, mas, ultrapassando o tamanho do array.

```
for (let i = 0; i <= chegada_alunos.length; i++) {
    (...)
}
```

Você está contando da posição 0 até o limite do array. Deve usar o ( tamanho -1 ) ou apenas < na comparação.

Desta forma a função aberturas, que possui o mesmo erro esta passando um elemento de array inexistente o que causa o erro na outra função, tornando o caso um pouco mais difícil de ser encontrado as vezes.

Vale lembrar ainda que ambas estão com o mesmo problema no *for*.

Segue abaixo uma possível correção ao erro em si.

```js
var alunosDaSegunda = [10, -5, 3, 0, -2];
var alunosDaTerca = [5,-3,-8,-15,0];
var alunosDaQuarta = [0, -5, 4, 5, 10];

console.log( acontece(alunosDaSegunda, 2));
console.log( aberturas([alunosDaSegunda, alunosDaTerca, alunosDaQuarta], 2));
 
function acontece(chegada_alunos, min_alunos) {
  var alunos = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < chegada_alunos.length; i++) {
       if (chegada_alunos[i] <= 0) {
           alunos = alunos + 1;
      }
  }
  return alunos >= min_alunos;
}

function aberturas(dia_aulas, minimo_alunos) {
  var aulas_v = [];
  for (let a = 0; a < dia_aulas.length; a++) {
    aulas_v.push(acontece(dia_aulas[a], minimo_alunos));
  }
  return aulas_v;
}
```